# Warning for explicit-shape array reshaping

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

Let all routines be inside modules.

1. If I pass the array `real*8 aa(5,3)` to a routine

   ```
   subroutine sub(bb)
   real*8, intent(in) :: bb(2,5)
   ...
   end subroutine
   ```

   with the statement `call sub(aa)` this will compile without a warning and the first 2 **columns** of `aa` will fill the `bb` array. The elements of the arrays `aa` and `bb` are aligned very differently.
2. If instead the routine is written

   ```
   subroutine sub(bb)
   real*8, intent(in) :: bb(:,:)
   ...
   end subroutine
   ```

   then `bb` would have the same shape and storage order as `aa`.

**Q:** The first behavior is quite dangerous if one forgets that there are explicit-size declarations in a routine. Can I make the compiler warn when explicit-shape arrays change shape/alignment?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a compiler option to warn about this as it is a perfectly legitimate practise using the *storage association* - we have several questions and answers about this concept. It can be quite useful.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. And before modules/interfaces it was probably the only way to do things. Anyway, it would be useful to have flags to disallow it or warn about it!